# Check for existing entries in Database or recreate table?

Tags: php, mysql, compare

I've got a PHP script pulling a file from a server and plugging the values in it into a Database every 4 hours.

This file can and most likely change within the 4 hours (or whatever timeframe I finally choose). It's a list of properties and their owners.

Would it be better to check the file and compare it to each DB entry and update any if they need it, or create a temp table and then compare the two using an SQL query?

Comment: how big is the file? What fraction of data changes on average? How much is completely new records, how much is existing records that change?

Comment: Currently around 50kb big, about 2000 lines. It doesn't have any user interaction, it is simply run by cron.

It will likely be a small amount of updates and a small amount of new ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None.

What I'd personally do is run the `INSERT` command using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (assuming your table is properly designed and that you are using at least one piece of information from your file as `UNIQUE` key which you should based on your comment).

**Reasons**

Creating temp table is a hassle. 
Comparing is a hassle too. You need to select a record, compare a record, if not equal update the record and so on - it's just a giant waste of time to compare a piece of info and there's a better way to do it.

It would be so much easier if you just insert everything you find and if a clash occurs - that means the record exists and most likely needs updating.

That way you took care of everything with 1 query and your data integrity is preserved also so you can just keep filling your table or updating with new records.

Comment: That's a much more elegant solution that what I suggested. =) I did forget to mention though that I will also need to delete any DB records that are no longer in the file. Is there an easy way to do that as well?

Comment: Deleting is a different beast :) what comes to mind quickly is `DELETE FROM <table> WHERE <some key> NOT IN(<list of keys you get from file>)`. Naturally, this might be slow, inaccurate and what not, depending on the file size and your MySQL configuration. Run it after you do the `INSERT`.

Comment: I figured it would be something like that. Thanks for the "NOT IN" tip though, I really should read up on mySql. =) Cheers for the help.

Comment: You might have noticed that SQL is really really close to human language, don't be afraid to experiment :) I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to download the file and update the existing table, maybe using REPLACE or REPLACE INTO.  "REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted."  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have a list of columns that will have to match in order for you to decide that the two things match.

If you create a UNIQUE index over those columns then you can use either `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`([manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)) or `REPLACE INTO ...`([manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html))